# unix open file for write given file descriptor

Tags: unix

I want to open a file for write and I have been given the file descriptor for that file.

I know that fdopen can be used to write to the file as follows:

```
FILE * fp;
fp = fdopen(filedes, "a+");
fwrite("\n", sizeof(char), 1, fp);
```

Is there any other way to achive the same, i.e., write to a file given a file descriptor?

Thanks

Comment: Is the file descriptor open for writing?  If so, then `write(2)` and its relatives work fine.  If not, then you have a tough time; you can't readily work out the name of the file corresponding to the file descriptor (it might not even have one - consider a pipe or socket).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any other way to achive the same, i.e., write to a file given
>   a file descriptor

You can write directly using the system call `write(2)`.

```
write(fd, "\n", 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a buffer of data to a file descriptor with the `write` system call.